# MySQL allows records longer than varchar(N)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

We have a database with a field of type `VARCHAR(255)` but in it I can see some records having a length of larger than 255, such as 264. How can it be possible? Can it be that the database is corrupt? Or somehow MySQL allows larger records? Or is there a known bug?

MySQL version: 5.5.47

Charset: utf8mb4

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHAR_LENGTH` - you presumably have some > 1 byte characters and `LENGTH` returns bytes.

You can read more about the string functions in the manual:

[MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual / Functions and Operators / String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html)